# Insert value multiple times into array based on argument passed

Tags: javascript

I have a array like this:

```
var oldArr = [2,3,4,2,3,5,6,4,2,3,2];

var newArr = [];
```

I am passing a argument(number) to a function which should insert values from oldArr into newArr taking the argument as `length` for each element found in old array.

```
function getNumbers(num){
        console.log('value passed is ', num);
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
      newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
    console.log('newArr', newArr);
}
getNumbers(2);
```

For example,

```
if I pass number 2 as in getNumbers(2);

new array output should be:

[2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6] //as the argument/length passed is 2.

if I pass number 3 as in getNumbers(3);

[2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6] //as the argument/length passed is 3.
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: what do you do with the old array's values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var oldArr = [2,3,4,2,3,5,6,4,2,3,2];

var uniqueArr = oldArr.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return index == self.indexOf(elem);
})
console.log(uniqueArr)


function getNumbers(num){
  var newArr = [];
  for(var i=0; i<uniqueArr.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<num;j++)
      newArr.push(uniqueArr[i]);
  }
  console.log('newArr', newArr);
}
getNumbers(2);
getNumbers(3);
```

Remove all your duplicates from your old array using [Array#Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) , then loop through all element and store it in new array.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
var oldArr = [2,3,4,2,3,5,6,4,2,3,2];

function getNumbers(arr, num){
    return Array.from(new Set(arr))
        .map((e) => new Array(num).fill().map(v => e))
        .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b),[]);
}

console.log(getNumbers(oldArr, 2));
console.log(getNumbers(oldArr, 3));
```

First of all, you need to get the unique values from the array. That's the `Array.from(new Set(arr));`.

Secondly, we can allocate new array for each number (to be able to nicely flatten it later). That's what `new Array(num).fill().map(v => e))` does. Result of this will be like `[[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]..]` etc.

And lastly, flatten it all using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=b).

Answer (score 1):

The following function should work

```
function duplicateN(oldArray, newArray, N) {
  for (var i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      newArray.push(oldArray[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

It simply iterates over each value in the original array and then inserts it N times.

I'm not sure the usage of this, but if newArray is always empty, something like this would be more maintainable

```
function duplicateN(inputArray, N) {
  var duplicatedArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      duplicatedArray.push(inputArray[i]);
    }
  }
  return duplicatedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [2,3,4,5];

    function getNumbers(num){
    var j = 1;
    var newArr = [];
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++)
       {
          j = 1;
        while(j<=num){
            newArr.push(arr[i]);
            j++;
          }
        }
        console.log(newArr.join());
    }
getNumbers(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using chain of `Array.prototype` methods:

```js
var oldArr = [2,3,4,2,3,5,6,4,2,3,2];

function getNumbers(num){
  return oldArr
   .filter((elem, index, arr) => !arr.slice(index + 1).includes(elem))
   .sort((prev, next) => next < prev)
   .reduce((result, elem) => result.concat(Array(num).fill(elem)), [])
}

console.log(getNumbers(2));
console.log(getNumbers(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  let multiply_array = (arr, mi = 1) => 
  [].concat.apply([], arr.filter((i, ind) =>
  arr.indexOf(i) == ind).map(i =>
  Array(mi).fill(i)));
```

The `multiply_array` function takes two parameters, an array and the multiplying integer. It filters through the array and finds all unique values by comparing position. It then maps over all the remaining unique integers and replaces them with an array that is the length specified by the passed in multiplying integer, and filled with the unique value. All of it is concatenated together to form one array.

```js
var oldArr = [2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2, 3, 2];
var newArr = [];

   let multiply_array = (arr, mi = 1) => 
   [].concat.apply([], arr.filter((i, ind) =>
   arr.indexOf(i) == ind).map(i =>
   Array(mi).fill(i)));

console.log(multiply_array(oldArr, 3));
```